# Hilbert space of random VECTORS?

Tags: bayesian, actuarial-science

I'm trying to break through H. Buehlmann and Gisler's Cource in credibility theory. At the page 183 they write that we have to show that
$$ \boldsymbol  \mu (\Theta_i)-\widehat{\widehat {\boldsymbol \mu(\Theta_i)}} \perp \boldsymbol X_{kj}$$ for all $k$ and $j$. All these vectors are $p$-dimensional random vectors, e.g.
$$ \boldsymbol X_{kj}=(X_{kj,1}, \ldots, X_{kj,p})^T.$$
The authors write that projections of random vectors are to be understood componentwise. Hence I deduce that orthogonality is also to be understood componentwise and that the above means
$$ \mathbb \mu_l(\Theta_i)-\widehat{\widehat {\mu_l(\Theta_i)}} \perp X_{kj,l},\ l=1,2,...,p.$$
But a moment later to prove this orthogonality the authors calculate a matrix of expectations
$$ \mathbb E[ (\boldsymbol \mu (\Theta_i)-\widehat{\widehat {\boldsymbol \mu(\Theta_i)}}) \boldsymbol X_{kj}^T)] $$
(I suppose that for all $i,j$, and $k$).
I'm asking: why? Why do we calculate a whole matrix of expectations instead of a vector of expectations? I'm really confused becuase of the multitude of indices here :( I'm in a muddle. The authors don't explain this very thoroughly.

On one hand if the matrix equals to 0 it implies that
$$ \langle \mu_l(\Theta_i)-\widehat{\widehat {\mu_l(\Theta_i)}}, X_{kj,l}  \rangle= \mathbb E[( \mu_l(\Theta_i)-\widehat{\widehat {\mu_l(\Theta_i)}}) X_{kj,l}]=0 $$ for all $l$, but on the other hand the authors during their proof use the fact that $\boldsymbol B_i:=\mathrm {Pro}(\boldsymbol \mu(\Theta_i)|L_e ^{ind}(\boldsymbol X_i))$ (orthogonal prodjection) where
$$\boldsymbol X_i:=(\boldsymbol X_{i1}, \ldots, \boldsymbol X_{in})$$
and hence (allegedly)
$$ \mathbb E [(\boldsymbol \mu (\Theta_i)-\boldsymbol B_i)\boldsymbol X_{ij}^T]=\mathbb E [(\boldsymbol \mu (\Theta_i)-\boldsymbol B_i)\boldsymbol B_i^T].$$
If the orthogonality is to be understood componentwise I don't quite understand why this equation should be true since
$$ \mathbb E [(\boldsymbol \mu (\Theta_i)-\boldsymbol B_i)\boldsymbol X_{ij}^T] $$ is a matrix -_-
Can you help me?

Comment: Could you please give some context, explain the notation?

Comment: Have you looked into RKHS...reduced kernel hilbert space methods?